# Is there a limit on the length of the JCLBEGIN attribute in CUPS DRV/PPD files?

Tags: cups

I am using CUPS 1.4. I have a DRV file with a long Attribute "JCLBegin". When I use ppdc on the drv file, the generated *JCLBegin is apparently truncated at 1024 characters. Is this a limit? If so, is there a way around it? I have to use Kodak KDK files and I need to specify a KDKSlip that has 500 page numbers in it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like almost all the string variables in cups have a length of 1024. I edited them all to be 9999 and rebuilt cups 2.0.2 and it solved my immediate problem.

Comment: Be aware that the DRV file is used to compile it into a PPD. But according to the PPD specification written by Adobe in the last century, a line length shouldn't exceed 255 characters. *(If it works for you, good for you! -- but you're outside the spec. To be inside the spec, use one of the officially supported line continuation methods.)*